# Using auto-complete for palette model in wicket

Tags: java, autocomplete, wicket

Is there any possibility in wicket to make a palette acting as auto-complete?

Comment: What would it mean for a palette to act as auto-complete?

Comment: I use wicket framework, and I have a Palette model in my page (which is a swap box, you can select items from a list to another list, http://wicketstuff.org/wicket13/compref/;jsessionid=0C21DAE33AEA747F88B44AC8A44A5F35?wicket:bookmarkablePage=:org.apache.wicket.examples.compref.PalettePage), I want it to be auto-complete, that means when user enters "a", it offers all the options started with a.

Comment: when user enters "a" where?  In a textfield associated with the palette?  And do the options starting with a then appear on the left?

Comment: Actually I mean entering "a" in left box and offering items starting with "a" there (the same left box), and if it is not possible, a text box associated with it as you described.

Comment: The easiest way is a separated textfield, in your case the `AutoCompleteTextfield` which is made exactly for that. With the help of Ajax you can then send your updated list to the Palette.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to do it!

Answer (score 2):

dumb, yes you can its quiet difficult, i did it  months ago its no exactly the same code but hope helps:

you need a form for submit the field where you are searching, then modify the models and finally redraw what you need

the original class is written in spanish sorry for any strange thing :S

```
 public SearchPallete() {

currentMedics = database action


avaibleMedics = new LoadableDetachableModel<Collection<? extends YourModel>>() {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<YourModel> res;

    @Override
    protected Collection<? extends YourModel> load() {
    res = get from database list of avaibles;



    res.addAll(add current assigned model);

    return res;

    }
};
//form for auto submit with ajax (it could be refactor)
ajaxFormPallet = new AjaxFormSubmitBehavior(palleteForm, "onchange") {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4029493502490267181L;

    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {


    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

    }
};

IChoiceRenderer<YourModel> renderer = new ChoiceRenderer<YourModel>(
    "field", "field");
pallete = new Palette<YourModel>("pallete",
    currentMedics, avaibleMedics, renderer, 10, false) {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected Recorder<YourModel> newRecorderComponent() {
    Recorder<YourModel> recorder = super
        .newRecorderComponent();
    recorder.add(ajaxFormPallet);
    return recorder;
    }

    @Override
    protected ResourceReference getCSS() {
    return new PackageResourceReference(MedicosTratantesPage.class,
        "theStyle");
    }

};
//for ajax 
pallete.setOutputMarkupId(true);

    //pallete form
palleteForm = new Form<FormMedicosTratantesModel>("palleteForm") {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5036201492891006829L;


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected void onSubmit() {
    //search and submit stuff

    }
};

searchField = new TextField<String>("Buscador", thethingToFind);

searchForm = new Form<String>("searchForm") {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void onSubmit() {
    pallete.detachModels();

    }
};
searchForm.add(searchField);

searchField.add(new AjaxFormSubmitBehavior(searchForm, "onkeyup") {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7939356732729920901L;

    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
    log.debug("searchField cambio");
    target.add(pallete);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

    }
});
add(palleteForm);
add(searchForm);
palleteForm.add(pallete);

}
```

Comment: thanks, unfortunately I don't understand what you have done! I'm going to ask a new question about possibility of auto-complete in a text area  within wicket.